# Input type=file" drag-and-drop IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm looking for a way to utilize drag-and-drop with the standard file input tag. It works in Google chrome, but not in internet explorer (11).

What I've done so far is adding a drop-event listener which gives me access to the file in the input parameter.

What I want to do is to add this file to the files of the input element.

HTML:

```
 <div class="files" id="fieldAttachments">  
       <input id="attachments" type="file" class="form-control" droppable />
 </div>
```

Javascript/angular:

```
el.addEventListener(
    'drop',
    function(e) {
        debugger;
        if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

        $('#testfilefield').prop("files", e.dataTransfer.files);

        console.log('files added');

    },
    false);
```

Like I said, this works well in Chrome but not in IE. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: try ng-flow-standalone.js https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow   I recently added to our project, works fine with drag-and-drop and IE9+ as well

Comment: do you get errors? does the console.log works ?

Comment: I would prefer to use the standard file object as we are already using a library (jquery multifile.js).

Comment: No errors unfortunately. But I did read that the property is read only due to security reasons. It does work in chrome though..